# Google calendar smart sheet sync disabled

Tags: api, synchronization, google-calendar-api

The below is the error thrown at the google calendar settings page. Despite of mentioning all credentials, such as email id and password in a .php file this API fails to work and I doubt may be because of this issue the calendar may not working good.

**How to fix the below issue?**

**Screen shot of error message**

[image]

**Error Message :**

> Events from Smartsheet:  NOTE: Sync is
>   disabled for this Google Calendar because the associated Smartsheet
>   has been deleted, or your permissions have been removed.